# Android Studio Build Error: "Content is not allowed in prolog."

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build

I have created a brand new project with no editing done to any code and when I go to run the code I get this error. The error is in *"Execute taskAction$gradle"* and is caused I believe by *"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;"*.

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.iterator(CompositeFileCollection.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getSingleFile(AbstractFileCollection.java:59)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.registerAaptService(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:83)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.registerAaptService$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.registerAaptService(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.getResourceProcessor(MergeResources.java:172)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:224)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.handleIncrementalInputs(IncrementalTask.kt:107)
...
```

The above is the start of the error message and the below is the end of the error message.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/aapt2/3.5.3-5435860/8486d2ab77c5f5659feca22c0c2da01d74f65541/aapt2-3.5.3-5435860.pom; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader.parseToDom(PomReader.java:256)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader.access$100(PomReader.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader$2.transform(PomReader.java:142)
    ... 170 more
```

Keep in mind I have edited the code in no way. I had an application running a few months ago and am not sure what changes i made then but when i started to work on a new application this is the error i received. I have uninstalled and reinstalled, and have deleted the .android folders, still getting this error.

**Gradle Plug-In Version**: 3.5.3, 
**Gradle Version**: 5.4.1, 
**Android Studio Version**: 3.5.3,

Comment: Looks like you have a corrupt download in your Gradle cache for 3.5.3 of the Android Gradle Plugin. You could drop back to 3.5.2 of the Android Gradle Plugin. Or, you could try to clean out broken files in the Gradle cache.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

1).Close android studio.

2).Delete all the contents of below directories.

```
                 C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\build-cache
                 C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\cache
                 C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle\caches
```

3).Start Android Studio.

Comment: Do you know how to find this cache folder on mac?